# Can I make the following IQueryable linq statment generic

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, linq-to-sql

Is there a way I can make the following db query builder generic?

```
private IQueryable<Foo> ByName(IQueryable<Foo> dbQuery, Query query)
{
    string[] searchTerms = query.Data.Replace(" ","").ToLower().Split(',');

    if (query.Exclude)
    {
        return dbQuery.Where(x => searchTerms.All(
            y => y != x.Name.Replace(" ", "").ToLower()));
    }

    return dbQuery.Where(x => searchTerms.Any(
        y => y == x.Name.Replace(" ", "").ToLower()));
}
```

I've got the same function for lots of different properties of Foo. ByCounty, ByTown, ByStreet etc etc.

I've written some functions that return linq before like the following

```
public Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> FoosAreWithinDistanceFromGeocode(
    double distance, Geocode geocode)
{
    double distanceSquare = distance * distance;
    return foo => ( SqlFunctions.Square((double)(
        foo.Address.Geocode.Easting - geocode.Easting)) +
        SqlFunctions.Square((double)(fooAddress.Geocode.Northing - 
        geocode.Northing)) ) <= distanceSquare;
}
```

But I can't seem to find if the Linq-to-SQL stuff can't use generics or if it's possible to pass properties as generics and that kind of thing.

---

EDIT: I have this working generically for a single search term.

```
Where [query.Data == "Foo1"]

return dbQuery.Where(SearchMatch("Name", query.Data));

public Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> SearchMatch(string propertyName, string searchTerm)
{
    var foo = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "foo");
    var prop = Expression.Property(foo, propertyName);
    var search = Expression.Constant(searchTerm);
    var equal = Expression.Equal(prop, search);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(equal, foo);
}
```

Anyone have any ideas how to make it work for an array of strings?

Comment: Are you using LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Objects/LINQ-to-XML? It turns out the LINQ-to-SQL is much more restrictive **at runtime**, throwing exceptions processing the same code that perfectly works with object or XML-based data sources.

Comment: Hah, I recognise `FoosAreWithinDistanceFromGeocode` :)

Comment: How can I tell if i'm using linq-to-sql or linq-to-objects?  I'm using a code first model if that helps?  The IQueryable creates a big sql statement before I execute it on .ToList()

Comment: Going down the expression builder route is possible, but time-consuming and a bit hair-raising because you give up a lot of the safety the compiler gives you. Before you set off down that path, have you considered building the predicate inside the Query object?

Comment: You're going the wrong way with this; you're throwing away compile-time checking for runtime checking.

Comment: True, however I've got lots of meta properties based on that object.  So say i have Foo and Foo has an object of FooMeta which has 50 columns "String1", "String2" and so on which can be used for setting up user defined tags.  I'd far prefer to be able to have a generic way of searching this data than have the hassle of writing about 50 more methods purely for the benefit of statically typing the data.

Comment: @Neil Added a type-safe way to call your `SearchMatch` function and get compile-time checks on the properties in my answer.  When you say "how to make it work for an array of strings", you need to show a sample of what you're trying to achieve.  I'm assuming you want something akin to a `Contains` call, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @casperOne if you look at the top bit of code I do an "All" and an "Any" call depending on whether I want to include or exclude the results.  The data passed in can either be a single search term i.e. "Foo1" or multiples i.e. "Foo1,Foo2,Foo3"

Comment: The `All` is easy, you can loop through all the search terms and keep calling `Where`.  The `Any` is not as much, as you have to get all the search terms and build a composite "or" statement with all of the queries.  Or, you can construct that entire lambda expression, but that's going to be a pain.  You might want to look at the code in Reflector, as it will tell you how to build that expression tree, which you can then substitute the property expressions for in a method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define an interface that exposes the properties that you want to access, like so:

```
public interface IHaveName
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Then, on your classes, you would implement the interface:

```
public class Foo : IHaveName
```

If you're using the classes generated from a DBML file, these classes are marked with the [`partial` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) so implementing the interface is as simple as creating a new file, and inserting:

```
public partial class Foo : IHaveName
```

Since the property is already declared as public in the *other* .cs file generated from the .dbml file, the interface is implemented implicitly.

Finally, you would rewrite your `ByName` method to take a generic type parameter with a constraint that it implement your interface `IHaveName`:

```
private IQueryable<T> ByName<T>(IQueryable<T> dbQuery, Query query)
    where T : IHaveName
{
    // Everything else is the same.
```

For your other properties (and methods which use them), you could aggregate them together into one interface, or separate them out, depending on your needs.

---

Based on your edit, if you want to create an expression dynamically, you don't have to give up compile-time safety:

```
public Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> SearchMatch(
    Expression<Func<Foo, string>> property, string searchTerm)
{
    var foo = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "foo");
    // Get the property info from the property expression.
    var prop = Expression.Property(foo, 
        (property.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo);
    var search = Expression.Constant(searchTerm);
    var equal = Expression.Equal(prop, search);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(equal, foo);
}
```

Which you then call like so:

```
var expression = SearchMatch(f => f.Name, "searchTerm");
```

This ensures that the properties that you are passing to `SearchMatch` actually exist on `Foo`.  Note if you wanted to make this generic for other scalar property types, you would do the following:

```
public Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> SearchMatch<T>(
    Expression<Func<Foo, T>> property, T searchTerm)
{
    var foo = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "foo");
    // Get the property info from the property expression.
    var prop = Expression.Property(foo, 
        (property.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo);
    var search = Expression.Constant(searchTerm);
    var equal = Expression.Equal(prop, search);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(equal, foo);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood what you are trying to achieve reflection might help you. At least if you play nice. Here's a simplified but working example

```
internal class Program
{
    private class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("My name is {0} and I'm living at {1}", Name, Address);
        }
    }

    static Expression<Func<Data,bool>> BuildExpression(PropertyInfo prop, IQueryable<string> restrict)
    {
        return (data) => !restrict.Any(elem => elem == prop.GetValue(data, null));
    }

    static IQueryable<Data> FilterData(IQueryable<Data> input, Expression<Func<Data, bool>> filter)
    {
        return input.Where(filter);
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        List<Data> list = new List<Data>()
                               {
                                   new Data {Name = "John", Address = "1st Street"},
                                   new Data {Name = "Mary",Address = "2nd Street"},
                                   new Data {Name = "Carl", Address = "3rd Street"}
                               };

        var filterByNameExpression = BuildExpression(typeof (Data).GetProperty("Name"),
                                                     (new List<string> {"John", "Carl"}).AsQueryable());

        var filterByAddressExpression = BuildExpression(typeof(Data).GetProperty("Address"),
                                                     (new List<string> { "2nd Street"}).AsQueryable());

        IQueryable<Data> filetedByName = FilterData(list.AsQueryable(), filterByNameExpression);
        IQueryable<Data> filetedByAddress = FilterData(list.AsQueryable(), filterByAddressExpression);

        Console.WriteLine("Filtered by name");
        foreach (var d in filetedByName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Filtered by address");
        foreach (var d in filetedByAddress)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Hovewer, I'\m almost sure it won't work with LINQ-to-SQL. One way to workaround it is to materialize the `IQueryable` before passing it to such filtering methods (e.g. by calling `ToList` on them).

Comment: You can definitely build the expression at runtime, but you don't get any type checking.  Why rely on a convention that can only be checked at runtime when you can rely on a compile time error (well, you'd only do this if you can't modify the entity classes)?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid calling ToList, I want to build the expression completely then sent it off.  

Looks like I should be able to do it with something like the following

ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter( typeof(Foo), "Name" );

Then creating a lambda expression to use in the where using the parameter and some other logic

Comment: I just tried this method but it comes back with an exception on the GetValue expression. => ExceptionMessage=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object, System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.